# How to search an Excel sheet for a specific date using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I've been using the example code given to search the sheet's contents:

```
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet1) {
 for (Cell cell : row) {
  CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getCellNum());
  System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
  System.out.print(" - ");

  switch(cell.getCellType()) {
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
          System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
          System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println();
  }
 }
```

}

But can't find a way to properly compare the dates extracted from the sheet with a given date. I've tried using a data validation and also formatting the date to a string and including further conditional statements but nothing has worked.

seems like a relatively simple problem and necessary to but havent been able to fix it yet?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel stores dates as floating point decimals which is - obviously - different to the way Java handles dates (`long` values).

Apache POI contains a helper class to do date conversion between Java and Excel: [`DateUtil`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html). This should help (if I got your problem correct).

Comment: managed to play around with DateUtil and got some sort of solution converting to strings and getExcelDate, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you read a number from the sheet, even if you read it as a string, you will get the number as decimal.

What I do, I keep all data in the cells start with underscore '_', so if I try to read data from any cell as a String, I don't get decimals or anything.

```
String cellValue = cell.getValueAsString(); // assuming the cell value is "_01/01/2011"
cellValue = cellValue.substring(1);// this will ignore first character, the '_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) class (Apache POI):

```
 DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
 String cellValue = df.formatCellValue(Cell cell);
```